# debounceTime not limiting api calls

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs5

I have this code:

```
await commuteReportService.getAddresses(query).pipe(debounceTime(1000))
            .subscribe((response: AddressesAPIResponse) => {
                console.log('execute call', response);
            });
```

However, in the network tab I still see that all the requests are being sent. This code is used in a autocomplete component where I want to limit the calls being sent.
I'm using rxjs 5.5, React and Typescript.

Comment: it is hard to see what is going on with only this function, however, add this after your debounceTime(1000) -> pipe(debounceTime(1000), 
      distinctUntilChanged())

Comment: debounceTime(1000) just delay the api call, not limiting. I assume your api call get called after 1000 ms. after each keyboard press on the input field

Comment: Maybe it is throttleTime that I need, however thats also not working. I don't want to send a request on every keypress.

Comment: You should debouce clicks, not api calls.

Answer (score 2):

`debounceTime` is only applied to whatever comes after it, meaning it only applies to your 'subscribe' — not `getAddresses(query)`, which is where I assume you're making calls.

Consider this minimal example:

```
// html
<input type="text" id="example" />

// js
const input = document.getElementById('example');

Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(input, 'keyup')
  .map(v => {
    console.log('called')
    return v.target.value;
  })
  .debounceTime(500)
  .subscribe(val => {
    console.log(`Debounced: ${val}`);
  });
```

Even though `Debounced...` is delayed, you'll still see `called` being logged to the console on every keystroke. If we change the order

```
// js
Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(input, 'keyup')
  .debounceTime(500)
  .map(v => {
    console.log('called')
    return v.target.value;
  })
  .subscribe(val => {
    console.log(`Debounced: ${val}`);
  });
```

Now both `Debounced...` and `called` are delayed ([Here's the fiddle for the code above](https://jsfiddle.net/8yojx39n/)).